# Promisify aws-sdk via bluebird

Tags: node.js, bluebird, aws-sdk

Folks, I am able to make a simple call to SES:

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var SES = new AWS.SES();

SES.listVerifiedEmailAddresses(function (err, emails) {
    console.log(err,emails);
});
```

However, when I try using `bluebird`, I get the following:

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var SES = new AWS.SES();
var ses = Promise.promisifyAll(Object.getPrototypeOf(SES));
ses.listVerifiedEmailAddressesAsync().then(function (err,emails) {
    console.log('p',err,emails);
});
```

error:

```
Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined
```

So, how does one promisify the aws-sdk via bluebird?  Need to be able to `return` results of successful promises.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `var ses = Promise.promisifyAll(SES);`?

Answer (score 2):

The Following bit works, Thank you @victorkohl

```
var SES = new Promise.promisifyAll(new AWS.SES());

SES.listVerifiedEmailAddressesAsync().then(function (err,emails) {
    console.log('p',err,emails);
});
```